# cakephp unable to register a user "You are not authorized to access that location"

Tags: php, cakephp

in cakephp3 i ame unable to register a  user and "You are not authorized to access that location" message is displayed.

In my AppController.php :

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [          
        'authorize' => ['Controller'],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ],
    ]);
}

public function isAuthorized($user)
{
     return true;
}

public function beforFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['register', 'confirm', 'login']);
}
```

and in my UsersController.php i have a function register() that i want to call to perform the registration of users.

Comment: Do you have proper execute permissions set on files?

Comment: Thinks for you reponse.

Comment: No i dont have any permissions beside that i use in the UsersController.php that code : 
    $this->Auth->allow(['register', 'confirm', 'login']);

Comment: Do you have a `beforeFilter` method in your `UsersController` too? If so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your function name is wrong.

```
function beforFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['register','confirm','login']);
}
```

It should be:

```
function beforeFilter(Event $event) {
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow(['register','confirm','login']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above error can be caused by the CSRF component.

In case you are using CSRF component, you need to grant permission as below:

```
echo "Sync'ing acos"
bin/cake acl_extras aco_sync

echo "Granting permission"
bin/cake acl grant Role controllers/ControllerName
```

Eg.

```
bin/cake acl grant Manager controllers/Users
```

Then do not forget to restart the server.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using beforeFilter() in AppController,then try to use controller name a nd Method,

```
public function beforFilter(Event $event) {
    $this->Auth->allow(['Users.register', 'Users.confirm', 'Users.login']);
}
```

> Don't forget to use class "use Cake\Event\EventManager"

Comment: It still doesn't work. the "You are not authorized to access that location" message is always displayed.

Comment: Try this,
1. Remove your isAuthorized()
2. Remove "'authorize' => ['Controller']," this line from your auth component load,
Let know, whether it is working or not @Khalid

Comment: With the removal of isAuthorized() and 'authorize' => ['Controller'],  it still doesn't working.

Comment: her is my team viewer 628 424 141

Comment: Your TV id is wrong and there is not password @khalid

Comment: siry the password is m41f7w

Comment: No my id is : 628 424 141

Comment: Can i have youe email adress, so that i send you the project if you want to debug it.